# How to access `process` throughout an electron app?

Tags: vue.js, electron, parcel

I have no problem to access various `process.*` properties in my renderer/index.html, but I cannot even get them in the directly referenced `index.js`, not to mention `App.vue`... what is wrong here?

[image]

Also with a huge delay (in case, process depends on some onLoad()-ish things), all I get is *undefined*. I am using [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) as a bundler.

Answer (score 1):

Now, that was easy. m)

```
console.warn( window.process.versions.node )

setTimeout(function(){
    console.warn( window.process.versions.node )
 }, 500);
```